# Remove Profile.aspx?Username=Mike and replace it with: /Mike

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am working on a social networking site. A user has an own profile-page.

A profile-page link example:

www.example.com/Profile.aspx?Username=Mike

Is there a way to remove the Profile.aspx from the link? (the Profile.aspx references to a Profile.cs)

And is there an other way to remove ?Username= ?

I just would like to have a simple and clear link like: www.example.com/Mike

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible method you could use:

If you are on .NET 4.0 or higher you can use routing (as already mentioned by @Arsen.

Another way would be to use URL rewriting. With URL rewriting you can tell IIS to process each incoming URL and map it to a different URL. More information on URL rewriting can be found here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite